# Android statistic tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have a dice game in Android. I used Google Analytics to collect dice rolling information (how often specific doubles occur per roll) to verify fairness. I want to display this data to the user in an activity so they feel assured of fair play.

Is there a way to pull the data out of my analytics account for display? Is there a better service that I should use?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't used them myself, but Google provides [Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) for Google Analytics.